# Why is this making my data frame become values?

Tags: r, dplyr, as.date

I have no sample data but it is not an issue with computation or processing. the issue is that upon processing the first section, my data frame nv_industry_data1 shows up in the environment as data 948 obs. of 9 variables. When I run the second line, it shows up as values with Date [1:948, format: "2007-09-01"... and so on. Can anyone explain why the second code chunk changes this from data to values?

```
   nv_industry_data1 <- nv_industry_data1 %>%
   mutate(month = case_when((period =="01") ~ "03",
                       (period == "02") ~ "06",
                       (period == "03") ~ "09",
                       (period == "04") ~ "12"))



  nv_industry_data1 <- as.Date(paste(nv_industry_data1$year, nv_industry_data1$month, 1, sep = "-"))
```

Comment: It is because you are assigning the data.frame object to a vector `nv_industry_data1 <-`. the `as.Date` is a vector of Date class.  Instead you may create a column in the same data i.e. `nv_industry_data1$Date <- as.Date(paste(nv_industry_data1$year, nv_industry_data1$month, 1, sep = "-"))`

Comment: `as.Date` converts it strings to date. Inside the function the code is "pasting" together the year and months so that R can understand